# Updating JBoss Remoting version 2 to 5?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I maintain a server client system build upon `JBoss Remoting` library version 2.5.0.SP2. The system consists a modular client, a central server which runs as registry/router and specialized servers which contains the application logic, database access, etc.

For the communication it implements `java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler` with a `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` object on the client side (internally uses `org.jboss.remoting.Client` and `org.jboss.remoting.InvokerLocator`) and uses `org.jboss.remoting.transport.Connector` on the server side to publish the application logic.

The whole system is around 7 years old and it should be modernized, because some components got incompatible with JRE 7 and 8, like JBoss Serialization, and on the security side it lacks for the support of authentication.

I found out that JBoss Remoting is actively developed and updated to version 5, but it seems that there is no documentation about it since version 3. The developers of JBoss Remoting say April 2016 about the missing documentation in a issue on github:

> [[...] it has grown into a very internal project, used to underpin several of our services but generally hidden from users.](https://github.com/jboss-remoting/jboss-remoting/issues/68#issuecomment-215074863)

I used a sample client and server and updated it to run with JBoss Remoting 5.0.6 to check if it runs ([gist with the source](https://gist.github.com/fireandfuel/d7fbc0fe446fa3105bb4729d7f9078c1)). I noticed while developing that the `org.jboss.remoting.Client` is gone and I didn't find inside `JBoss Remoting` anymore.

The developers of `JBoss Remoting` mentioned that it's possible to implement RCP over it (see quote above). I figured out that `JBoss Remoting` is part of the WildFly application server which uses it.

Is it possible to implement RPC like `JBoss Remoting` version 2 without using the whole WildFly application server (using EJB)? If yes, how?

If not, is there a good alternative for it?

Comment: I checked out `org.jboss.remotingjmx:remoting-jmx:3.0.0.Final` first. It works, but as JMX is only allowed to access getter and setter methods, not all methods. I skipped EJB implementation using `org.wildfly:wildfly-ejb3:12.0.0.Final` because it depends on the majority libraries of WildFly.

Comment: I implemented a server and client based on the samples, I adjusted the `java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler` implementation for invoking over a simple custom build protocol. So, the question is done.